# Gstreamer v4l2src failed to allocate buffer when run on a Jetson Nano

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to run a Gstreamer pipeline that duplicates a video stream so it can be used in two applications. Here is my sample pipeline that fails when run on a Jetson Nano, but works on my Ubuntu PC.

I have used `v4l2loopback` to create 2 v4l2 devices (/dev/video1 and /dev/video2) like so:

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=1,2`

PRODUCER:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2`

CONSUMER:

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! xvimagesink`

As you can see I'm trying to use `tee` to duplicate the stream and send it to 2 `v4l2` devices that I created with v4l2loopback.

When I run the consumer, it displays the first frame, then crashes with:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Failed to allocate a buffer
Additional debug info:
gstv4l2src.c(998): gst_v4l2src_create (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0
Execution ended after 0:00:00.056466348
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Any idea on why it fails to allocate a buffer? And why doesn't this happen on my Ubuntu PC?

Here is my full Jetson Nano pipeline that uses the camera and splits the stream into 2 v4l2 sinks:

`gst-launch-1.0 nvarguscamerasrc ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM), width=1920, height=1080, format=NV12, framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! nvvidconv ! tee name=t ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video1 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video2`

Answer (score 0):

The error disappears by using the `max_buffers=2` argument in `v4l2loopback`. I can't explain why it doesn't need this option on my Ubuntu PC, must be something to do with the amount of available memory?

Curiously, increasing `max_buffers` to something higher (eg `max_buffers=8`) causes the **same** *Failed to allocate buffer* error.