# VideoCapture Release - Failed to Allocate Buffers (V4l2src) Jetson NX

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I'm using a v4l2sink in gstreamer to tee a video stream that I can access in OpenCV. This works when I open the videocapture device and get frames, however at some point I want to release the capture device and reopen it later in the program. When I release the device, I get the following errors:

```
[ WARN:7] global /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (488) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to query pipeline state
[ WARN:7] global /tmp/build_opencv/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1761) handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Failed to allocate a buffer
```

I open the capture device like so:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("v4l2src device=/dev/video3 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM) ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=BGRx ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink drop=1 max-buffers=2")
```

release it like by using `cap.release()`
and my gstreamer pipeline is:

```
"gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=2560,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! tee name=t ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=0 brightness=50 t. ! queue ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3"
```

I create the v4l2loopback device using:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback video_nr=3 max_buffers=2
```

I had to specify max_buffers=2 because I was facing the same issue as this post: [Gstreamer v4l2src failed to allocate buffer when run on a Jetson Nano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029291/gstreamer-v4l2src-failed-to-allocate-buffer-when-run-on-a-jetson-nano) where I got the failed to allocate buffers error at the start.

The main issue arises when I try to reopen the pipeline and capture device, because gstreamer gives me a reason not negotiated error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for your case, but I'd try adding `identity drop-allocation=1` before v4l2sink for a v4l2loopback node:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=2560,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! tee name=t ! queue ! xvimagesink sync=0 brightness=50   t. ! queue ! identity drop-allocation=1 ! v4l2sink device=/dev/video3
```